# nodejs stream pipe into already piped N streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I want to pipe one stream to N already piped streams, the code below returns only `here2` it doesn't go in the first transform stream. It seems that piped streams doesn't behave like one stream.

```
'use strict';

var stream = require('stream');
var through2 = require('through2');

var pass = new stream.PassThrough({objectMode: true});

var transform1 = through2.obj(function(obj, enc, done) {
    console.log('here1');
    this.push(obj);
    done();
}).pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, done) {
    console.log('here2');
    this.push(obj);
    done();
}));

pass.write({'hello': 'world'});

pass.pipe(transform1).on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pipe` method returns the destination stream. So the `transform1` stream is actually the 2nd stream in the pipe chain. Eventually you are writing `pass` stream to the 2nd stream only (hence the output is always 'here 2'): Try this:

```
pass.pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, done) {
    console.log('here1');
    this.push(obj);
    done();
})).pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, done) {
    console.log('here2');
    this.push(obj);
    done();
}));

pass.write({'hello': 'world'});
```